# How to make UIPickerView Opaque in iOS7?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiview, uipickerview, alpha

I created subclass of UIView that contains UIView with UIToolBar and UIPickerView instance. So hierarchy is something like following, things is brackets indicate property values set for individual view.

```
 UIView (alpha = 0.85f, backgroundColor = grayColor)
    |
    UIView (alpha = 1.0f, backgroundColor = whiteColor)
      |
      UIToolBar
      UIPickerView (alpha = 1.0f, backgroundColor = whiteColor)
```

Now despite of all the values set up my UIPickerView looks transparent in iOS7. Is there something else am I supposed to set up ?

Answer (score 1):

I didnt get anywhere with the background color, or adding other subviews ..

in the end what did work, it's a kludge but the other solutions didnt work for me, I put a label behind the picker, in the same view heirarchy.  then the picker transparents onto the label which is opaque.

Comment: What do you mean??